# Close() en MongoDB con Node.js driver con múltiples updates

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Estoy tratando de escribir un script en Node.js que actualice mediante updates una colección en MongoDB. Tengo N pacientes (sus IDs en un array) y para cada uno quiero actualizar los datos en la colección con un objeto. Los documentos pueden no existir previamente.

Ahora mismo estoy haciendo

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
...
    var collection = db.collection('datasample_second');

    for(var i=0;i<PatientIDs.length; i++){
            collection.update({'timestamp' : epoch_sec, 'patientID' : PatientIDs[i] }, 
        updateObj, 
        { upsert: true }
    );
    }


      setTimeout(function() {
        db.close()
      }, 2000);

}); //MongoClient.conect
```

y me he visto obligado a poner ese último timeout ahí para que el bucle pueda disparar los updates a base de datos y darles tiempo a ejecutarse antes de cerrar la conexión. A priori en lugar del *timeout* tenía simplemente *db.close()* y claro, sólo me entraba el primer update y para los otros recibía un mensaje tipo "socket closed".

Este apaño funciona mientras sigo con otras cosas, pero no me gusta. He estado intentando encontrar algo mejor con la documentación del driver de Node.js para MongoDB, pero no he encontrado nada.

Sé que a *update* le puedo pasar como cuarto parámetro una función de callback, en la que podría cerrar la conexión. Mi problema es, de nuevo, que no puede hacer el *close* tras el primer update, si tras mandarlos todos.

Quizá sería más fácil también hacer un único update, pero como digo los documentos no siempre existen (de ahí el *{upsert : true}*) y con cada *update* quiero insertar/actualizar tantos documentos como pacientes tengo en el array PatientIDs.

Intenté usar un `$in` para la query, pero al no encontrar ningún documento preexistente mongo hace un único update sin el campo *patientID* en el objeto.

Hay alguna manera de detectar que los updates se han realizado para después hacer el close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrías que contar los updates terminados y cerrar después del último

```
var to = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("tarda mucho cierro igual");
    db.close();
  }, 2000);
var updatesFaltantes=PatientIDs.length;
for(var i=0;i<PatientIDs.length; i++){
        collection.update({'timestamp' : epoch_sec, 'patientID' : PatientIDs[i] }, 
    updateObj, 
    { upsert: true }, function cerrarDespuesDelUltimo(){
        updatesFaltantes--;
        if(!updatesFaltantes){
            db.close();
            clearTimeout(to);
        }
    }
);
}
```

Lo del timeout quizás sea exagerado pero lo dejé.

Comment: Buena solución. La modifiqué un poco para que se decremente el contador sólo si no hay error en la llamada. Según la documentación esa función de callback debería recibir _function (err, numUpdated)_ pero por numUpdated siempre obtengo NaN. Viendo que el [update devuelve _null_](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#update) descarté hacer nada con esa función callback.

Comment: Creo que si te da error igual deberías contarlo. Si no te va a quedar la base abierta (salvo que mantengas el time out). Otra cosa, el timeout debería ser proporcional a la cantidad de datos a guardar + un valor fijo

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. He mantenido el timeout, pero es cierto que decrementar en el callback pase lo que pase sería suficiente para decir, literalmente "El último que cierre" :-). Gracias de nuevo por la ayuda.